# Copy the shape from a UIView to an other UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, alpha

I have a UIView with a custom shape (see image), I would like to dim that view sometimes with a black tint. However, just pulling down the alpha doesn't work for me, since that uses dim it.

So I thought of adding a subview to the view with the same shape and dim that view with an alpha, so it will look like the lower-bubble (see image). How can I copy the shape of an view, do I need to subclass it again or is there an easier way?

[image: The image]

Comment: How are you drawing the shape?  Is it an image in an image view?  Do you draw it in `drawRect:`?  Do you use a `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: Its an UIView, I draw it in `drawRect:` using `CGContext`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it by drawing a new UIView on top of the existing UIView and giving it an 40% black color. 
Since I drew the view once, I could draw it again.

Answer (score 2):

You're drawing the shape in `drawRect:`.  So just draw it with a darker color.  Give your view a `dimmed` property, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL dimmed;
```

Override the setter like this:

```
- (void)setDimmed:(BOOL)dimmed {
    if (dimmed != _dimmed) {
        _dimmed = dimmed;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Then check the property in `drawRect:`.  If it's set, use the darker color.  Otherwise, use the lighter color.

Comment: However, the darker color it set upon the yellow background. The alpha of 40% black (0,0,0) should apply to the bubble view and all its content (e.g. the red text). You suggestion would only change the background to an other desired color.

Comment: Why can't you change the text color too?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do this with a lot of customly created UIViews then the most easy way I can tell is to take that shape into an image editor like Photoshop, fill it with black color, make its transparency at around 30-40% and overlay it over the destination view.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion but thats not an option for me unfortunatly. the view is reused at different times at different sizes.

Comment: I suppose by different sizes you mean that you compose this view from its upper - rect and lower - arrow parts, where arrow is always the same size? If you have that view subclassed, you could still stick to this approach by creating two dimmed images for both rect and the arrow

Comment: The arrow react differently at different time. Also different sizes, places ect. I prefer the programmatic way.